# Питон, нужна помощь

Tags: python

Как сделать так,что бы когда появляется один текст,другой пропадал я не могу допедреть

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import time as t

print("Текст 1")
t.sleep(3)       #задержка в 3 секунды, чтобы мы смогли разглядеть текст 1
os.system("cls") #очищяет экран
print("Текст 2")
```

Comment: А что если делаешь на телефоне

Comment: @ДляТиктока тогда сочувствую